# FB.UI does not show thumbnail when secure browsing is enabled

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, https, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using FB.UI api to allow users to post to their wall, here is the code for that:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: name,
    link: linkPath, 
    picture: thumbnailPath,
    caption: iconName,
    description: 'Come check out my my awesome post'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {

      alert('Post was published!');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published!');
    }
  }
);
```

Normally this works fine and the Facebook dialog pops up showing the picture linked from "thumbnailPath", but when I use a test account that has enabled secure browsing, the thumbnail does not show up and when it is posted to the wall there is no picture.  I am running this off of a MAMP Pro server and I created the certificate using MAMP's "Generate self signed certificate" feature, so it is not a valid certificate.  I am wondering if this is the reason that my thumbnail won't show up.  When I goto the path linked by the variable "thumbnailPath", it shows up just fine.  I have tested this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and I get the same behavior in all browsers.

I am wondering if my invalid certificate is likely to be the cause of this issue, or does that not make sense?  I have been unable to find any other links online that describe similar problems so I am unsure if this has anything to do with my certificates.

Comment: Can you send us your site URL? Also have you tried the facebook URL Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug (the old url linter)?

Comment: @Whiteagle The app is at: https://apps.facebook.com/267332333367949/, after you save it will bring up the dialog, the site requires you to have a webGL enabled browser.  I had not tried the debugger.  When I run it, the only warning i get is about images being at least 200px in dimensions.

Comment: Unfortunately the app is with errors and I cannot get there, also I can't access the page, maybe due to your ssl certificate (also you may want to think on buying one before going live, don't forget you'll also need a dedicated IP address).
Have you tried to run it with the HTTPS url there? And can you see the share image there? If not have you trying to open the image that facebook gives you there and see if there is any error there?

Comment: Ah yes I had forgot about that problem with the https.  If you goto https://scalablegamedesign.cs.colorado.edu directly you should be able to accept that bad certificate and then you won't get that error.  When I run it with the https link I provided I do not get the image in the dialog or see it when posted to a wall.  Not sure what you mean with your last line.  Open the the image where?  Thanks for taking a look at my problem

Comment: that's not the problem, check out the app page, it has an SQL error.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, I am getting the same issue as you using Chrome and Firefox (but Safari works after allowing the certificate).  Chrome gives this error: Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.  Sounds like it might be related to the certificate, also it works fine for me if you goto http://apps.facebook.com/267332333367949/ looks like I'll have figure out this certificate thing before I can really go any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply making sure to always link the the thumbnail with an http address instead of an https address, one I did this the thumbnail would always show up.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a valid certificate, then FB cannot/won't scrape the object over https including metadata like the image.  Get a real cert, then make sure FB can scrape your url using the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Also, if this is a brand new object and nothing has been published on the object, then FB doesn't know it exists (and won't have a thumbnail to show).  You can initiate a pre-emptive scrape using the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or programmatically with a GET/curl (see "Updating Objects", https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/ ).

When publishing an app on apps.facebook.com (Canvas), you also need a valid cert for secure browsing.

If you are just testing the app, then you can put your app in Sandbox mode using the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), which will let you, admins, testers, and other people you define in the Roles section use the app on Canvas with http (not requiring secure browsing).

Comment: Sadly I have added a valid certificate and the problem still persists.